# What is the difference between check and domain constraint in database?

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

I am studying relational database. While reading about the constraint the domain constraint and check seemed similar to me. What are the exact differences between them?

Comment: `CHECK` is a "SQL clause" that allows you to implement domain constraints.

Comment: CHECK can "operate" on multiple columns (like `CHECK (a < b)`). And as far as I didn't miss something, there are no domains in MySQL.

Comment: They are 2 things. Where are you stuck in understanding what either of them is in what presentation in documentation, a manual or a textbook? See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

Domain constraints are a user-defined data type which is a definition of a valid set of values for an attribute and we can define them like this:
*Domain Constraint = data type + Constraints (NOT NULL / CHECK / DEFAULT)*

As you can see CHECK is one of the ways in which a domain constraint can be applied.

For Example: Let's say, I have a table called *student_info* and I want to add a field called *stu_id* whose value should always be greater than 100, then the domain constraint will look like this

```
create domain id_value int
constraint id_test
check(value > 100);

create table student_info (
stu_id id_value PRIMARY KEY,
stu_name varchar(30),
stu_age int
);
```

Here id_value is of type int and has a constraint to check if the value is greater than 100 or not.

[Reference](https://www.javatpoint.com/dbms-integrity-constraints).

Comment: `UNIQUE` constraint on a domain? Are you sure? The same for `PRIMARY KEY` and `FOREIGN KEY`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I did not understand the concern completely.  I was thinking that constraints like NOT NULL / UNIQUE / PRIMARY KEY / FOREIGN KEY are also a constraint on a column so can be defined in the same definition. Do you think technically domain constraint should always have "create domain" command also?

Comment: Read more about it here https://www.javatpoint.com/dbms-integrity-constraints. You are right. Domain constraint is a type of constraint and is limited to the value of the field. Corrected the answer.